# moving live php application to local server wamp

Tags: php, localhost, wamp

I tried moving my live php website to local server WAMP ver 2.4 on windows 7 but my index.php is not rendering correctly and giving errors. **I tried doing it on other hosting server and it worked fine** there.

The errors or rendering issues which i am getting are 
1. Script in index file is getting displayed as it is for e.g.

```
$msg = "";
if ($_REQUEST['submit']) {
    $date_cont_new_object = new WebsiteDate();
    $date_cont_new_object_array = $date_cont_new_object->curntDate();
    $date = $date_cont_new_object_array['DATE_TIME'];
    $value = new validate_contact();
    $name = $value->check_input($_POST['name']);
    $email = $value->check_input($_POST['email']);
    $phone = $value->check_input($_POST['phone']);
    $query = $value->check_input($_POST['query']);
    $captcha = $_POST['captcha'];
    $msg = $value->check_cont_form($name, $email, $phone, $query, $captcha, $date);
} ?>
```

2. script getting displayed as it is

'.$bbsectortbl['sectname'].' ('.$numberofsectorid.')'; } ?>

3. Notice: Undefined variable: bb3 in ...\index.php on line 306
4. Notice: Undefined variable: bb1 in ...\index.php on line 309

few more...

I think that the problem is of setting on local server.

Any help on this is appreciated as i trying to solve this past 1 week with not much luck. 
Thanks

Comment: Which framework u used?

Comment: means? I am directly coping my files from live server /public_html files to local WAMP  (c:/wamp/www) directory

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not WAMPServer, your problem is badly written PHP code.

I would imaging that your LIVE server has got `display_errors = Off` so you dont see the result of the bad code.

As WAMPServer is a developers tool, it comes configured for developers to **see** and hopefully **correct** their errors so it has `display_errors = On`.

So to get your code running with the errors made invisible to the client you need to edit php.ini and change that setting

Edit php.ini using the wampmanager menus

```
wampmanager -> PHP -> php.ini
```

Find

```
display_errors = On
```

and change to

```
display_errors = Off
```

You may also need to change this setting as well

From

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

to

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i was able to solve the problem
The issue was with tags i.e. , when i changed from

Hope this helps to someone looking of similar issue.

Thanks to all for your contribution and helping.

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty much sure that you need something like this: [setting wamp](http://tenfouragency.com/setting-up-a-wamp-local-server-on-windows-7/)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have setup my WAMP and it working fine but the issue is it is not working correctly (rendering problem) when i move my php app here from live server.